# to select data by time criteria from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Good Afternoon! Now I want to work with the financial data automatically and I have a problem how to select the required data from the data.frame.

For example, I have the following `head` `of data.frame`:

```
               period bid_open bid_high bid_low bid_close ask_open ask_high 
1 2015-01-02 00:00:00  1.20860  1.20880 1.20860   1.20870  1.20890  1.20890 
2 2015-01-02 00:01:00  1.20870  1.20880 1.20865   1.20865  1.20880  1.20890 
3 2015-01-02 00:02:00  1.20865  1.20880 1.20865   1.20875  1.20875  1.20885 
4 2015-01-02 00:03:00  1.20875  1.20885 1.20875   1.20885  1.20885  1.20900 
5 2015-01-02 00:04:00  1.20885  1.20885 1.20880   1.20880  1.20895  1.20895 
6 2015-01-02 00:05:00  1.20880  1.20885 1.20880   1.20880  1.20890  1.20895
```

The main attention is here in the first column `period` - the data can have the time frequency 1m (as below), 1s, 1h, 1d. And I want to write the function which will be to contain the parameter `frequency`. For example, if the `frequency=2h`, function output is new data.frame which contains the observations (stock prices) by 2h:

```
2015-01-02 00:00:00
2015-01-02 02:00:00
2015-01-02 04:00:00
....
```

If frequency is `15s` (f.e.) than the R has to output the inital data.frame since the frequency of initial data is 1m.

But I have several problems to realize that task. Can you help me, please?

My logics is:

Firstly, to find the initial frequency:

```
    time=data[,1]
freq=as.numeric(difftime(time[2], time[1]))
```

But problem is that the R shows only number (in this case `freq=1`) and I don't know it's 1m or 1h or 1d. How to correct it?

2. Secondly, f.e. I will obtain the `freq=5m`, but my data frequency is 1m, so I need to correct my table and to remain only `1st,6th,11th...` rows. How can I make it?
   Thanks!

Comment: For your output, if you select frequency = 5 minutes, do you want to get average values (i.e. output would be the avg. bid high for that period etc.) or do you want the exact value at that instant? Either is doable but you may not have values for some instants depending on your input data.

Comment: No, if frequency=5 minutes, but my data have every minute observations, I want to get the new data frame, where the old data will be as: data[1,], data[6,],data[11,] etc. so step = 5 (observations number 2-5 don't be used).

Comment: okay. For initial time step (frequency), you can use `difftime(time[1], time[2], units = "mins")` so you know the unit is minutes, for the rest, `lubridate` package should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible solution:

```
  # 1. Load library
  library(dplyr)

   # 2. Data set sample
   df <- data.frame(
      period = c("2015-01-02 00:00:00", "2015-01-02 00:01:00", "2015-01-02 00:02:00", "2015-01-02 00:03:00", "2015-01-02 00:04:00", "2015-01-02 00:05:00"),
      bid_open = c(1.20860, 1.20870, 1.20865, 1.20875, 1.20885, 00:05:00))

    # 3. Feature engineering
   df <- df %>% mutate(
     year = as.numeric(substr(period, 1, 4)),
     month = as.numeric(substr(period, 6, 7)),
     day = as.numeric(substr(period, 9, 10)),
     hour = as.numeric(substr(period, 12, 13)),
     min = as.numeric(substr(period, 15, 16)),
     sec = as.numeric(substr(period, 18, 19)))

  # 4. Select data function
  select_data <- function(df, str_frequency){

     # 1. Define frequency parameters
     frequency_value <- as.numeric(substr(str_frequency, 1, 2))
     frequency_type <- substr(str_frequency, 3, nchar(str_frequency))

     # 2. Calculate result by using modulus operator %%
     df_result <- df[!(df[, c(frequency_type)] %% frequency_value), ]

     # 3. Return result
     return(df_result)
  }

# 5. Test (filter for "02min" as a basic test)
select_data(df, "01year")
select_data(df, "01month")
select_data(df, "01day")
select_data(df, "01hour")
select_data(df, "02min") # should filter here / change to "03min" also works
select_data(df, "01sec")
```